# Converting Mapinfo ".Map" file into ArcGIS format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, convert, mapinfo, tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert MapInfo TAB and/or MIF to SHP?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp)

I currently do not have MapInfo but I do have a lot of ".Map" files that I need to convert for use in ArcGIS.

Actually each file (much like a shapefile i guess) is composed of several files:

```
Filename.DAT
Filename.ID
Filename.MAP
Filename.TAB
```

Comment: This is a probable repeat of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp which covers .TAB to shapefile conversions.

Comment: Oops. @Kevin is right. Please close this.

Comment: closed on request of original poster Jakub as a duplicate question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp is answered.

Comment: Install QGIS and use it to convert mapInfo to .shp http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344/18320

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapinfo TAB to ESRI Shapefile can be done in ArcGIS provided you have the 'data interoperability' extension (FME based conversion tool in ESRI clothing).

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/index.html

To do this free:

**Ogr2Ogr** will convert to shapefile from tab.

http://www.gdal.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks. No interoperability extension. As for Org2Org. Is there something that has a GUI? Add a file with a button, click convert, etc.

Comment: http://www.ogr2gui.ca/en/index.php