# Creating DEM after converting MapInfo tab files to ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, tab

How do I create DEM for contours after converting MapInfo tab files to ArcGIS and how do I convert toposheet tab file to ArcGIS?

Comment: There are answers on this subject already. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp etc. Have a look on the forum first.

Answer (score 2):

Use ArcGIS Data Interoperability Extension to convert mapinfo tab files to arcgis compatible.
Then use XToolspro to create dem from contour.

Comment: Their are any papers based on this

Answer (score 2):

If licensing is available then Data Interoperability or FME to convert data from MapInfo TAB seems like a way to go.

To turn the contours into a DEM you may want to consider the [Topo to Raster tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Topo_to_Raster/00q90000000s000000/) that is described in more detail [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000030000000) but needs a 3D or Spatial Analyst license to use.