# MapInfo TAB into ArcGIS10 problems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, convert, mapinfo

I am having a difficult time working with ArcGIS. My files are in TAB format.

In ArcGIS I use the QuickImport tool.

I am able to select the input file, but it does not let me click on "OK". Any hints on that?

I have checked this thread:
[Converting MapInfo TAB and/or MIF to SHP using free tools or ArcGIS for Desktop core product?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp)
but I could not find a similar problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right license extension to use this tool? you know the data interoperability tool should installed separately.

Comment: You could always convert to a more Arc friendly format (.shp) using OGR as suggested in the link you posted, if it is urgent and you can't figure out a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use Arcmap WITH the data interoperability extension, FME Suite, Autodesk Map3D, or MapInfo to convert these files.