# What to do with .map .id .tab files

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I found some maps from my state government that I wanted to I downloaded what I thought was a zipped up map perhaps as a bitmap. However, upon opening the zip file I found a large number of  .map .id .tab files. I take it that there is a program that can open all these files and create a map on my desktop. Can anybody tell me how to work with these files?

Comment: You have "MapInfo TAB" format data.  To read them in ArcGIS you need to convert them, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24788/mapinfo-tab-into-arcgis10-problems and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/converting-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp-using-free-tools-or-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: QGIS can open them too, then convert to shapefile.