# Convert Ordnance Survey NTF data to QGIS compatible format

Tags: qgis, import, ordnance-survey

Is there a way of converting Ordnance Survey NTF data to QGIS that will correctly import the data and build polygons?

QGIS will read the data as is, but it imports the polygons only as centrepoints.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the open source tool [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) which has a command called [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) which can convert NTF files into a range of vector formats, either using the various language bindings (including python) or at the command line.

FME can also read NTF files so a custom workbench could be created to read in your files, perform any initial processing, if required, and then convert them to whatever format you need. FME is not free, but you can get a free trial which would support your needs in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for these, both new to me so we'll give them a go.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [MyGeo Data Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/). It's an online conversion service which can convert ntf to

- ESRI Shapefile
- Microstation DGN
- MapInfo File
- Comma Separated Value (.csv)
- GML
- GPX
- KML
- GeoJSON

You can also try [ESRI's Productivity Suite](http://www.esriuk.com/software/arcgis/productivitysuite). It's not free but they do have a [30 day trial version](http://www.esriuk.com/software/arcgis/productivitysuite/download).

Comment: Edited to include a link. My bad. Pressed save too early.

Comment: I've used productivity suite but there is no chance we can get a full license for that.  MyGeo Data Converter still only seems to convert the polygons into points, and even then not all of them. A good service though so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

**NTF to MIF** is a free translator available from here - http://www.bodley.ox.ac.uk/guides/maps/translat.htm

for Shapefile use GDAL
see [Converting MapInfo TAB and/or MIF to SHP using free tools or ArcGIS for Desktop core product?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-do-i-convert-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp)

This will only convert to lines - so there will be another post-process required afterwards to build polygons.

Either convert to shapefile or postgis and build polygons using numerous tools in QGIS to do this Geoprocessing tools with help with that.

Depending on the size number of NTF files needing to be converted it might be better to use postgis.
Then use ST_BUILDAREA https://postgis.net/docs/ST_BuildArea.html