# Can shapefiles be converted to .TAB files?

Tags: mapinfo, tab

I read this response to this question, "Yes, if you have access to MapInfo, you can directly read Shapefiles (as .shp is an "open" format) and save it as TAB files!"

Once it is saved as a .TAB, are you then free to modify the data in MapInfo?

Comment: Answer is here http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326/97

Comment: Isn't the whole point that a .tab file is a native MapInfo file?

Comment: @whuber, depends on your definition of "Native".  MapInfo will open the file and you can read it and query it, however, it doesn't allow you to edit it unless you convert it to TAB.

Comment: @Fezter Thank you.  I think I'm missing something here, though: we are talking about TAB files themselves ("once it is saved as a .TAB") so no conversion is needed.