# Driver error when converting MapInfo file to Shapefile with ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, mif

I am trying to convert a MapInfo file to an ESRI shapefile using `GDAL`'s `ogr2ogr` command [as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326/12871), but I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `Iceland2pts.mif' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> a bunch more drivers listed...
```

Just to be sure I have updated my GDAL install to the latest version (1.10.1) on Ubuntu, so I'm thinking it has to do with the format of the file ([due to this](http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/fwtools/2010-July/001819.html)), but I just don't know enough about these to know what is going wrong.

**Example format of MapInfo file**:

```
VERSION 300
Charset "WindowsLatin1"
COLUMNS 0
DATA
REGION 156
 4
        -22.556955         64.777794
        -22.555510         64.782730
        -22.544556         64.779297
        -22.546009         64.777359
 5
        -22.493431         64.767670
        -22.486217         64.774597
        -22.483826         64.772453
        -22.486826         64.768799
        -22.493431         64.767670
```

Does the formatting look incorrect, or is something else eschew?

Thanks!

**Update:** Example of the possible `MID` header

```
VERSION 300
Charset "WindowsLatin1"
COORDSYS Earth
PROJECTION 1, 104
COLUMNS 0
DATA
REGION 1
19814
        -23.8252        65.7438
        -23.8289        65.7445
        -23.8355        65.7472
        -23.8421        65.7503
        -23.8477        65.7531
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [MapInfo site](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/spatial_server/english/1_0/onprem/apiguide/LIM/source/UserDefinedSpatialDatabases/mapinfomifmidformat.html):

> MIF/MID format is comprised of two files,
>   one with an extension of MIF, the other with the same name, but the
>   extension MID. The MIF file contains the actual points that represent
>   the objects, while the MID file contains the text information about
>   the objects.

The MapInfo MIF [format specification](http://resource.mapinfo.com/static/files/document/1074660800077/interchange_file.pdf) notes that the .mid is optional, but the GDAL/OGR [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mitab.html) refers to "a pair of .MIF + .MID files" and a quick test using a [MIF](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/ticket/5141/nomid.mif) with no MID shows that `ogrinfo` fails when the MID is missing.

It looks like your MIF is not supposed to have an associated MID (i.e `COLUMNS 0`) so it seems like this is a bug in GDAL/OGR.  I've opened a [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5141) (and in only a few hours it's been [fixed in trunk](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5141#comment:1) scheduled for release in GDAL 2.0).

Comment: Thanks Luke. I had thought that I had two different `MIF` files, as one had the extension `.mif` and the other `.MIF`, but perhaps this is the `MID` file you refer to. I will include the header of this file to my post for more info and give your suggestion a shot. Thanks for filing the bug report!

Comment: @shootingstars no, that 2nd file is a MIF, the format specs I linked to explains the difference. MIFs have the header and geometry, MIDs have only the attributes. Your files do not have MIDs and gdal/ogr cannot open them. A workaround might be to add a dummy column, see [example MIF](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/branches/1.10/autotest/ogr/data/small.mif) and create a dummy MID with a dummy value for each feature in the MIF. Alternatively, checkout gdal trunk from the subversion repo and compile from source (ask a new question if you need help with that).

Comment: Great. Thanks Luke. I'll give that a go ASAP and get back to here.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain you can't get away with COLUMN 0. You need at least 1 (dummy) field, but you can skip the MID file and it will create default values for all fields.
At least, that is how MapInfo works.

Comment: You mean I should just make it `Columns 1` rather than `Columns 0`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, COLUMNS 1 and "Dummy CHAR(1)" on the next line.

Comment: Tried changing `COLUMNS 0` to `COLUMNS 1` and adding `Dummy CHAR(1)` in a new line below it, and I am still getting the error. I also tried `"Dummy CHAR(1)"`, just to be sure that wasn't want you meant.

Comment: ogr2ogr may need the MID file (MapInfo doesn't). So, try to create the MID file too with dummy values.

Comment: COORDSYS Earth
PROJECTION 1, 104

Comment: This should be a on single line in the MIF