# ArcGIS for Desktop adds fields to *.tab table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a tab-delimited table. The file is a `.txt` file with the `.tab` extension. The rows are:

```
Dataset Feature_Class_or_Table  Field   GLOBALID    New_Value   Bad_Character
GasDataset  CasingAnno  TEXTSTRING  {5A5B2C4B-F395-4AD2-BEB8-D1AB3D61DDC2}  3/4 -4  new line, carriage return
GasDataset  CasingAnno  TEXTSTRING  {832D9957-CEA2-4DDE-801A-4A12F286681C}  2 PL-34 new line, carriage return
GasDataset  CasingAnno  TEXTSTRING  {66441560-5EF1-4572-B13B-F7C4970CD2C1}  2 PL-30 new line, carriage return
GasDataset  CasingAnno  TEXTSTRING  {EF2B66AF-E957-47AA-A23F-1334E085C5A4}  1 1/2 PL    new line, carriage return
```

However, when ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop reads the table, it adds a couple new fields; `New_Value_X` and `New_Value_Y`.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the reading/creation of these two fields?

Comment: can you post a link to the actual text file, eg on Dropbox?

Comment: I've posted a link to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe ArcGIS is grabbing the closest thing to a possible coordinate and converting it into two columns. With your first row for new_value being two separated numbers, even though not actual coordinates, ArcMap decided that that should be separated into an x and y column (new_value_x and new_value_y). By switching the order of your data, and moving that row down, I was able to import the table by 'Add Data' and not get the *_x, *_y columns.

A few solutions include manually manipulating the data, programatically wrapping strings in quotes, creating a header with dummy data for programatically loading in ArcMap that is easily stripped out later, etc.

For a little background on what is happening, [here is a help page from ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-an-ascii-or-text-file-table.htm)

> If your delimited text file contains data coordinate information, such
>   as x,y data, ArcGIS will recognize the coordinate information as
>   numeric fields which can be used to either display your information as
>   a layer or as input to tasks, such as geocoding. In the example above,
>   the coordinate information was straightforward and easy to recognize;
>   it was contained in fields called x and y. This won't always be the
>   case and, in many instances, the information you want to use within
>   ArcGIS may be stored in any number of different formats.
>
> If this is the case, such as when the coordinate information is stored
>   within a text field or is stored in degrees, minutes, and seconds (for
>   example, -120 13 58), the information will be converted and displayed
>   to you in Decimal Degrees (DD) for use in ArcGIS. **In the case of
>   single-field formats, such as UTM, ArcGIS will maintain the original
>   UTM field but add two additional fields appended with _X and _Y and
>   display the coordinate information in Decimal Degrees.** For example, if
>   you have a text field called UTM, when opening the text file, you will
>   see three fields called UTM, UTM_X, and UTM_Y. In the case of
>   double-field fields, such as Lat/Lon, when these fields are identified
>   as text fields, ArcGIS will maintain the original fields and add two
>   new fields to contain the converted Decimal Degree coordinate
>   information.

Also, if you are just looking to convert [a mapinfo tab file to shapefile, you may want to look at this question.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/converting-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp-using-free-tools-or-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: Great answer. It seems it's an over-zealous feature rather than a bug

Comment: Seems buggy to me  :)   3/4 -4 should not be assumed to be a coordinate.

Comment: yeah maybe I should have said "feature" with massive air quotes